# Regular Expression For Decimal with precision 5 and scale 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to validate a text box on key press and here is my criteria.

I need a regular expression which allows total of 5 digits and a decimal point.

If there's no decimal point then it should allow to enter 5 digits.

And if there's a decimal point then it should allow only 2 digits after the decimal point.

However the total number of digits should not exceed 5 digits excluding decimal point and it can be less than 5 digits.

And below is my regex

```
/^(?:\d{1,2}(?:\.\d{0,6})?)?$/
```

I hope I am clear and let me know if any clarifications needed

Please help Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a regex that just lists out alternatives separated by |:

```
/^\d{1,5}|\d{1,4}\.\d|\d{1,3}\.\d{2}$/
```

i.e.
1-5 digits with no decimal point OR 1-4 digits followed by a decimal point and one digit after the decimal OR 1-3 digits followed by a decimal point and two digits after the decimal.

Comment: if you want to allow numbers like .4 (i.e. zero digits before the decimal point), you can just update the above accordingly.